# Correct way to start SignalR client (async) from constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor web server application created that needs to have a SignalR client running.

I do not want to initialize the client from a web page. Rather, I would like to run it from a service class.

The problem I am facing is with correctly calling an async method from a constructor. See code below to understand better.

```cs
public class SignalRHubClient : ISignalRHubClient
{
    private const string ReceiveMessageMethodName = "ReceiveMessage";
    private const string SendMessageToAllMethodName = "SendMessageToAll";

    private readonly ISignalRMessageEventAggregator _signalRMessageEventAggregator;

    private HubConnection _hubConnection;
    private HubConnectionState _hubConnectionState => _hubConnection.State;

    public SignalRHubClient(ISignalRMessageEventAggregator signalRMessageEventAggregator)
    {
        _signalRMessageEventAggregator = signalRMessageEventAggregator;

        // Below line is my question. This is incorrect I feel.
        // Even using .Wait() is not good is what I read.
        Initialize().ContinueWith(async task =>
        {
            if (task.Exception != null)
            {                    
                await DisconnectAsync();
                ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(task.Exception.InnerException).Throw();
            }
        });
    }

    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
               .WithUrl("hubUrl")
               .WithAutomaticReconnect()
               .Build();

            _hubConnection.On<string>(ReceiveMessageMethodName, message => OnMessageReceived(message));

            await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // do something
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async Task DisconnectAsync()
    {
        // there is a chance that this could not work right in case of race condition.
        if (_hubConnectionState == HubConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            await _hubConnection.StopAsync();
            await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();

            _hubConnection = null;
        }
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(string messaage)
    {
        try
        {
            await _hubConnection.SendAsync(SendMessageToAllMethodName, messaage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    private Task OnMessageReceived(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyMessage>(message);

            _signalRMessageEventAggregator.PublishSignalRMessageReceived(new SignalRMessageEventArgs
            {
                Message = message,
            });
        }
        catch (JsonException ex)
        {
            // do something
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This class will be instantiated from `ConfigureServices()` of my `Startup` class in Blazor WebServer application.

```cs
services.AddScoped<ISignalRHubClient, SignalRHubClient>();
```

Most of the tutorials I see, mention to start the connection from a client web page using JavaScript. I do not want to do that, since I want to show notifications on multiple pages. Hence I want a single place to receive all SignalR messages and then broadcast it using the event aggregrator.

I also tried to create a static method that will return and instance of `SignalRHubClient()`, but not sure how to do it when Dependency Injection is involved. Note: I have few other items that are being injected. I just kept 1 for simplicity of code here.

Comment: _"The problem I am facing is with correctly calling an async method from a constructor."_ - Last time I checked, this was simply impossible to do.

Comment: I probably don't fully understand the idea properly here, but in general, have you considered creating a `BackgroundService` / `IHostedService` for this, starting the SignalR hub connection in its `StartAsync` method?